# Showing API data in Text Box

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, api, swifty-json

I'm trying to get a dataset from an API (already installed and set up) into a text box on Xcode, after pressing a button on the UI.

Below is the code I'm using:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var dataView: UITextView?
    @IBAction func getDataPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    APIManager.sharedInstance.getPostWithId(postId: 1, onSuccess: { json in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.dataView?.text = String(describing: json)
        }
    }, onFailure: { error in
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.show(alert, sender: nil)
    })
}
```

I've connected the @IBOutlet to a text box, and the @IBAction to a Button. Unfortunately I'm getting an error message (and a huge crash) every time I press the button.

A lot of the code was written through a tutorial, but the tutorial didn't explain very well how to carry out the function 'getDataPressed()' when the button gets pressed.

I'm new to coding so apologies if I'm not making sense - but can anyone help with this?

Comment: can you please share crash report?

Comment: It doesn't actually crash the app (ie. I don't get an error message on the terminal and the simulator doesn't stop working). It just freezes the app on the simulator, with an 'Error' at the top of the app, and then a black screen comes halfway across the simulator screen.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the error message in your question, but its a pretty safe bet that if its crashing when you push the button you may have the button triggering a selector that doesn't exist.  Right click the button in interface builder and delete the extra touch up inside selector by tapping on the X.

Comment: There's only one 'Touch Up Inside' selector. I removed it, linked the button to the function again, and now I'm getting a 'Thread 1: Breakpoint 2.1' error.